# What is the negative point in the knock down action?

Tags: phantom-doctrine

When you knock down someone, there is a negative point that shows below the experience line as you can see in the picture with a red arrow

[image: negative point]

What is that point referring to? What is it subtracting? From what total?

Answer (score 1):

It's the health/hitpoints from the enemies

[image]

[image]